# Merging issue with storyboard

Tags: ios, git, git-merge, xcode-storyboard, git-merge-conflict

there are more than three developers working on the storyboard and when we merge I can there are so many Conflict mostly with frames of Views..git shows

As its a autolyaout environment .. whatever changes frame shows can we just ignore ... is it something to be concerned of while merging ?

I honestly think in autolayout environment the frame related conflicts are due to the fact that these storyboards are opened in different display sizes and the frames have changed and we don't have to care about these conflict we can take either of one side.

Please correct me If I am wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My advice will be to split the Storyboard (with Storyboard reference). Split is wisely according to dev  task. So when u all commit, no conflict r done.

[Here theres a good Walk throw](https://www.raywenderlich.com/115697/ios-9-storyboards-tutorial-whats-new-in-storyboards)

Storyboard conflicts r a pain in the a.. If none did change anything in the Storyboard, just use any and ignore the rest. Not sure why those changes r made, personally i don't commit them if none change was done.

Comment: Thanks . But storyboard reference is not available in iOS 8.its from iOS U ... so splitting won't work.. Thanks anyway